# Best way to chain observable subscriptions in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have always nested subscriptions when I need to call a resource after getting the result of another one, like so:

```
this.paymentService.getPayment(this.currentUser.uid, this.code)
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(payment => {
        this.payment = payment;
        this.gymService.getGym(this.payment.gym)
            .valueChanges()
            .subscribe(gym => {
                this.gym = gym;
            });
    });
```

I am using Angular v6 and AngularFire2.

Both endpoints (getPayment and getGym) return objects. Is there any more elegant way to do this without nesting one call inside another?

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Comment: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are many resources available online to get an understanding of how this kind of scenarios can be addressed with rxjs.

Usually you end up using `switchMap` like this

```
this.paymentService.getPayment(this.currentUser.uid, this.code)
.pipe(
   switchMap(payment => this.gymService.getGym(payment.gym))
)
.subscribe(
   this.gym = gym;
)
```

I have skipped on purpose the `valueChanges()` call. I do not have any idea of what it does, but it does not sound as right in a reactive world.

This is a [nice article about `switchMap`](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/).

Comment: you should do > return this.gymService.getGym(this.payment.gym)

Comment: Isn't the assignment `this.payment = payment;` missing now?

Comment: @Wintermute you are right, if you need the payment in the component you need the assignement