# How to better write Subscribe within Subscribe Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a dialog and I subscribe to its afterclosed() method and if the result is true I call another service and subscribe to it.

I dont want to have a subscribe within a subscribe.

What is the better way to write it? I suppose Rxjs operators can help but how and why its better approach?

```
dialog.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result) {
        this.projectService.deleteProject(name).subscribe(
          () => {
            this.getProjects();
          },
          (error) => {
            this.alertify.error(error);
          }
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: Using the switchMap maybe?

dialog.afterClosed().pipe(switchMap(name => this.getProjects())).subscribe()

Comment: Thank you for the comment but can you make the code clear and explain it. I am new to Rxjs so it will be more helpful.

Comment: `mergeMap` seems to make the fewest assumptions. `switchMap` has semantics that don't seem applicable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to chain observable subscriptions in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51108217/best-way-to-chain-observable-subscriptions-in-angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the RxJS higher order mapping operators `switchMap`, `concatMap`, `flatMap` (aka `mergeMap`) or `exhaustMap`. Each has their specific use case. You could find a good write up [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/).

I'll use `switchMap` for illustration. I am also returning RxJS [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY) constant if the `result` from first request is false/undefined. It emits a `complete` notification without `next` or `error`. So neither of the functions `this.getProjects()` or `this.alertify.error(error)` is triggered.

```js
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

dialog.afterClosed().pipe(
  switchMap(result => {
    if (result) {
      return this.projectService.deleteProject(name);
    }
    return EMPTY;                 // <-- complete without `next` or `error` notifications
  })
).subscribe(
  res => this.getProjects(),
  error => this.alertify.error(error)
);
```